# Accessing base machine(win 2k8) from virtual machine hosted on it

Tags: windows-server-2008

I am new to Hyper v, i have windows 2008 machine, hosted 3 VM s of wind 2003 on it.. I want to install some softwares on the 3 VMs.. but not able to find a way to share the softwares with the vm from the base machine. tried to give an ip of same segment as the base machine, but its still showing crossed.

Am i missing something here ? Pleas help .. As the VM LAN is showing crossed. how do i actually enable it as it doesnt have a physical port.

P.S. Also some referene material for the same would be of great help as am totally new to this.

**update**

Yes, my network adapter is showing crossed, netword cable unplugged. Can you help me in rectifiiying this. I want it to access the base machine network.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a virtual switch, and are your VM's set to use this? Sounds like you have no network connectivity from your VM's at all, which would prevent you accessing any remote machines.